# JavaScript memory leak caused by function scope?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Using the chrome development tools i recently found out, that my application which uses a modular concept leaves over some Module objects in memory even if they are not referenced directly by any other of my application objects.

The Problem here seems to be, that they are referenced in some function scopes.

As you can see on the following screenshot:

[image]

there are a lot of references held in function scopes.

Here is a small part of code that demonstrates one of many ways how this happens in my application. Since `module` is referenced inside `someCallback` there is a reference i can't delete myself anymore.

```
function augmentModule(core, module){

   var someCallback = function(){
      module.stop();
   };

   module.listenTo(core, "someEvent", someCallback);
}
```

My question is:

Is this a real memory leak i have to worry about, or will this object be garbage collected at a later point in time by the JavaScript engine? Does the JavaScript engine knows "this object is only referenced from function and closure scopes and has no "real" references so i can delete it." ?

Comment: As long as your function is still running Chrome will keep the objects reference in its context in case it needs to look them up. You don't have any direct control over the garbage collector and it's best to leave it to the optimization engine anyway.

Comment: None of this functions is running. They're all terminated. Of cause i want to leave the garbage collection to the engine, i just want to make sure, that the engine recognizes this object as "deleteable".

Comment: Memory can be held by an object in two different ways: either by the object directly, or implicitly by holding references to other objects. This will generally prevent the garbage collector from automatically deleting them. If you have deleted all the references to an object, that means the object itself will become unreachable and will be disposed.

Comment: Well... actually.. i know that... and i managed to remove all references to the object that i am able to. But as you can see on the screenshot there are references in function scopes that i cannot delete to make the object unreachable.

Comment: What does `listenTo` do? are you binding event listeners?

Comment: Yes, listenTo is a part of Backbone.Events but they are all removed via "stopListening()". Note: this is just example code to demonstrate what happens.

Comment: Think of the heap as an interconnected tree-like structure. As long as you can reach the function scope, and the function scope can reach your object, your object is still linked. As long as you can reach the object via a path (_retaining path_), the GC will not delete it. You are returning `module`, which holds a reference to `someCallback` which can call `module` again. Be aware that `someCallback` will persist as long as it's referenced outside of the function scope. So, if you want to clear it up, make sure you delete all pointers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to implement a teardown method in your module subclases (augmenModule). The teardown method would unbind all observer functions that have been setup by the class on initialization. Call your teardown method when disposing of an object to release references and allow the associated memory to be garbage collected.

Comment: Actually this is what i already did. But nevertheless this is still the correct answer since it already worked. The references shown in the image don't matter for garbage collection. The objects are beeing disposed at some later point in time.

Answer (score 2):

In your example there is no actual problem. Variable "module" is referenced from the function, so it will be kept as long as the function is kept by someone. This is absolutely legit, as your function would need this object, once it is called. When your function is released, this reference will go.

However, you should be aware of the more subtle thing. If you should have several closures inside the main function, they all share one scope storage. This means, that some references could be kept in a closure, that doesn't even need them:

```
function m(ref0, ref1, ref2, ref3) {
   var cb1 = function(){
     return ref1 + ref2;
   };
   function notCurentlyUsed(){
     return ref2 + ref3;
   };
   ref0.doSomething();
   return cb1;
}
```

So,

- ref0 has nothing to do with closures, it is released when m finishes,
- ref1 is kept, it's needed by cb1, so it goes into scope storage that is kept by cb1,
- ref2 is kept, it's needed by both cb1 and notCurentlyUsed, so it goes into scope storage that is kept by cb1,
- ref3 is kept too, it's needed only by notCurentlyUsed, but the scope structure is shared, so it is kept by cb1 too.

Note that you can watch what is actually kept from Developer Tools, because function value exposes its .

Answer (score 0):

please expand the tree for the topmost retainer with smallest distance.
Actually this tree is the part of the graph that keeps you object alive.

So you should find out the object in the retainers tree which should be alive by design of you app which keeps a reference to the 'module' object directly or indirectly that has to be collected. This reference will be the root of problem. There is a chance that you have many such references. In that case you have to eliminate all of them.